# How to display image button inline with text in a table cell?

Tags: css, jsf, icefaces

I have a JSF 1.2 dataTable using ICEfaces 1.8. In one column, I would like to display the text from a backing bean, and then to the right of it, display a small image on the same line without it wrapping to a new line.

The image is actually a `ice:commandButton` component with the image attribute set.  The action of clicking on the image is to display a `ice:panelPopup` panel.

Here is the relevant code of the column within the dataTable:

```
<ice:column id="col1">
    <ice:outputText escape="false" value="#{document.column1Value}" />
    <ice:form>
        <ice:commandButton actionListener="#{bean1.open}" image="images/popup.gif">
            <f:attribute name="docParam" value="#{document.parameter}" />                           
        </ice:commandButton>
        ...
    </ice:form>
</ice:column>
```

I have tried all sorts of adding CSS style information to various tags, including `white-space:nowrap` and `float` but have been unable to get the desired effect.

Comment: I'm not sure if I see the problem. You've already put the text and the image button in a hacky 2-column table by `<ice:panelGrid>` and yet they are still presented below each other? Or are you actually asking how to achieve it without using a table?

Comment: @BalusC.  The image in the `<ice:panelPopup>` isn't the issue.  I guess I could have taken that component out but I included it just in case.  The problem is that the image displayed in the commandButton (images/popup.gif) is being displayed below the text coming from `#{document1.column1Value}`.  I'm trying to make them both display inline within their column cell.

Comment: Oh, I now see what you mean. I've removed some code noise from the question and posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<ice:form>` generates a HTML `<form>`, which is by default a [block level element](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html), so it always starts at a new line. You need to set the style of the `<form>` to `display: inline`.

```
<ice:form style="display: inline;">
```

Alternatively, you can also just move that text into the form.

```
<ice:form>
    <ice:outputText escape="false" value="#{document.column1Value}"/>
    <ice:commandButton actionListener="#{bean1.open}" image="images/popup.gif">
        <f:attribute name="docParam" value="#{document.parameter}" />                           
    </ice:commandButton>
    ...
</ice:form>
```

Either way, you only still need to prevent the cell's content from being whitespace-wrapped when there's little room left in the cell's width. You could achieve that by setting `white-space: nowrap` on the *common parent element* of the both elements. In case of the first approach (setting the form to `display: inline`), that would be the `<td>` element and in case of the second approach (putting the text inside the same form), that would be the `<form>` element. E.g.

```
<ice:form style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <ice:outputText escape="false" value="#{document.column1Value}"/>
    <ice:commandButton actionListener="#{bean1.open}" image="images/popup.gif">
        <f:attribute name="docParam" value="#{document.parameter}" />                           
    </ice:commandButton>
    ...
</ice:form>
```

*(note, the `style` attribute is in the above examples exemplary, in real you should be using CSS files instead with style classes)*

Comment: That got me to figure it out.  I moved the outputText inside the form and set `white-space:nowrap` on the form.  But to get it to work I had to add `display:inline` to the `<ice:outputText>`, which does not make sense to me because the tag only generates a `<span>`.  And looking at the CSS class that ICEfaces adds to the span, there is nothing that would cause that.

Comment: You're welcome. That makes indeed no sense. Perhaps the CSS for the span is changed elsewhere? Web developer tools like Chrome/Firebug/IE9 can show them all for a particular element when you do rightclick and *Inspect element*.

Comment: Ah yes, the span was getting set block display somewhere else.  I didn't see that before until I used Firebug.  Thanks.